# Is it correct to update the GLIBCXX / GLIBC on a shared hosting server?

Tags: centos, ssh, glibc, cpanel

I'm having issues updating node.js for a single user in a shared hosting server, which is being installed by NVM package.Whenever we try to switch versions to a newer one, this error is displayed:

```
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
```

As far as I'm concerned, those dependencies are locater in the root. But I'm not sure whether to proceed to the update or to leave it as it is...

My question is:

> Is there a way to update those libraries without affecting the rest of
> the server? Is there another way to update node  without affecting the
> rest of the  client of that server?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly are you switching to a newer one? Are you just trying to use a newer version that's been installed on the system?

Comment: No, I'm trying to update the node version the server has previously installed (currently 12.22.1) to a newer one (14.17.0) without affecting the  rest of the  server. However, to do so I'm required to update GLIBC and GLIBCXX (libraries?) because the newer version of node needs it to work properly.

Comment: What OS is this? Are you updating it via the package manager? Compiling source code? Downloading and installing a package file?

Comment: I'm tryng to update node via nvm, which is a package manager for node.

Comment: What OS are you using?